# PHP Apache request dying unexpectedly with Apache logs showing "Segmentation Fault"

Tags: php, apache, yii

I am using Yii 1 with PHP 7.1.33 running on an Apache/2.4.41 server macOS Catalina 10.15.3

In my application some of the requests are dying unexpectedly and randomly like this

[image: API Request dying example]

In this image two calls are being made to the same api but one is succeeding and other one is returning no response.

[image: no response]

I know the parameters are different but even when I am doing a die dump at the start of controller method, I'm getting the same result, first one succeeding, second one failing.

The same error is occurring with other apis which are in no way related to this api. And when this error is occurring, I am getting
`[Tue Mar 17 16:34:39.572039 2020] [core:notice] [pid 697] AH00052: child pid 1233 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`
in my apache logs.

Comment: I don't at all think Segmentation Fault is fixable.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Removed apache from local. Now using nginx with php-fpm